# Drupal Migrate - Assign Roles

Tags: migrations, users

I'm creating a Migration from our old website (non-Drupal) to our new Drupal website. On our old website, roles and role assignments were kept in 2 seperate tables. So far, I've written a simple UserMigration and a RoleMigration class. However, I'm in doubt how I should proceed for the RoleMembershipMigration.

In short: Should I manually load roles in a `prepare` function for the UserMigration, or should this be done in a seperate Migration class altogether? I'm inclined towards the first, since it is not actually a migration to a seperate entity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to join roles and role assignements tables togother in your query of RoleMigration class, 
in that case you will have these fields as source fields : `role_id, user_id, role_name`

now in UserMigration you just need to apply the dependency of the role migration on "roles" field :

```
$this->addFieldMapping('roles', 'role_name')
            ->sourceMigration('Role')
            ->defaultValue(drupal_map_assoc(array(2))); // authenticated user default value
```

Don't forget also that the key field of migration mapping should be the user_id field :

```
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
        array('user_id' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'User ID.'
                )
            ),
        MigrateDestinationUser::getKeySchema()
    );
```

Didn't test it but should work like that!